# How to resolve "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'"?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift4

I've seen examples of how to resolve this error but I can't get it to work in my case.

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'

Shouldn't `employeeCount` be optional since it is inferring the right side?

```
static func getEmployeeCount() -> Int {
    if let employeeCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "employeeCount") {
        return employeeCount as! Int
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [UserDefaults.standard.integer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer) return `Int`, not `Int?`. So you don't need to wrap it with `if let`.

The `optional` is irrelevant whether on right side.

In your case, just `return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "employeeCount")`